# Repressurising Logic Combi 24 boiler

Tags: plumbing, repair, heating, boiler

I bled a rad that was cold at the top, and not much water escaped. This fixed the rad, but the pressure in the boiler dropped to just below 0.3(It may have been low to begin with, since I hadn't checked this in a good while). I checked with the manual, and a couple of youtube videos of similar boilers, and then happy that I knew exactly what to do, I opened two valves on the filling loop(which was already attached by whoever installed it), expecting the boiler to re-pressurise... but literally nothing happens. I was wondering if anyone might know of a reason for this? I am quite sure all valves that should be opened, are. I haven't had any problems with the boiler before this.

Below are the instructions from the user manual.. my filling loop is basically in the state you see in the last picture(set up). Turning the valves as instructed does nothing.. Any help is much appreciated.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: 1-2 bar is approximately 15-30 psi with all the air out and pressure from a house faucet you should have more than enough water pressure. After the system runs the system may need additional air bled off. Large boilers have DA tanks (de-air) to remove the air from the system. I don't work on small systems but it sounds like you are doing it correctly. Is your pressure gauge good?

Comment: @EdBeal I assume it is. In every youtube video I've watched of people doing this, there is a rushing sound of water when they open the valves.. I hear nothing at all... it seems to me like there is no supply of (mains) water to the refill loop... any idea why that might be? (I've opened and closed all 4 valves connected to the loop in all the orders I can think of..)

Comment: I am sure you thought of this but could there be another shutoff for the main water supply?.  When you turn the valves watch the screw in the center of the valve if it doesn't turn the ball valve may be stuck in the closed position and the handle cracked / broken I have seen that in the past.

Comment: @EdBeal Thanks for your replies. I have posted a picture of the valves above. The problem valve, I believe is the blue one on the front left. I think you were right about the screw not moving, but as you can see, it's hard to get to(there's about an inch between the valve and bottom of the boiler). Any ideas what I could do about this? I can't get to it with a screwdriver. I'm not sure how I might turn the pipe around for better access or if I even should try this (I'm guessing I shouldn't)..

Comment: Seems like if the plastic handle was gone I could maybe turn it manually?

Comment: I don't see an additional photo but usually the shaft has a square that the handle connects. Make sure to note the position and use a small crescent wrench to turn it 90 degrees. Most ball valves will turn both directions. Once the system is pressurized return it to the closed position. A pair of pliers can also be used but the soft brass gets chewed up. If the valve is stiff work it both directions until it turns. Be careful not to use excessive force so you don't twist the stem off.

Comment: There looks to be a union that if loosened will allow the valve to be rotated so you can remove the handle and give it a try. Be careful because scale buildup can make the valve very stiff.

Comment: @EdBeal Thanks, but I'm not sure which part your referring to exactly.

Comment: Now I see your photos , I was thinking the nut after the valve could be loosened so the valve could be rotated but that doesn't look like an option from your photo.

Comment: @EdBeal Thanks for your advice. I'm going to get a small offset screwdriver, and try to turn the valve with that. https://www.amazon.co.uk/CONNEX-COXT411212-Ph1-100mm-Screwdriver/dp/B001B4TM9E/ref=sr_1_12?ie=UTF8&qid=1482434988&sr=8-12&keywords=offset+screwdriver

Comment: Have you had any luck? I put up a bounty but don't see any new help. If you figure it out in the next few days post as an answer, would hate to see 50 points go unclaimed

Comment: @EdBeal Thank you for that. Not as yet. I might have tried removing the plastic handle, but really don't know how to go about it. Tried pulling it up, but was cautious of breaking something. I have ordered an offset screwdriver from Amazon which looks like it might do the trick of reaching the valve's screw. Should get it in the next couple of days (no hardware shops I visited had anything similar of the right size). I will certainly report if that works. Fingers crossed!

Comment: @EdBeal Ok, so I have finally been able to turn the valves properly, and... nothing..there's just no water flowing in there. I really don't know. I have tried to trace the pipe in question back to the mains to make sure it's even connected... but surely it must be, since this is how the boiler presumably got filled originally? This is very odd, and I feel like I might have to call someone in.

Comment: @EdBeal I don't know if you can claim your own bounty, but if you would like I would accept an answer with your suggestions from above. They did help clarify and understand the situation a bit, which is what I was asking for.

Comment: I don't think I can and the system closed it. If you up vote the best comment that would be thanks enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I got a guy out to fix it. This was months ago at this point. However, he discovered that the fill loop had been put on "the wrong way around". I'm not a plumber, or person who knows about pipes, but I am assuming from his explanation that water simply couldn't flow either way through this small section of pipe... regardless, he said he put it on the right way around, and indeed I can now repressurise the system. I have no idea why the guy before this put the pipe on backwards..